# WiFi doesn't connect to specific networks

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I have had this problem since I upgraded to 18.04.
I can not connect to my University network.
Other Ubuntu users can. And I can connect to my home network or my hotspot network.
I tried using wicd instead of network manager, no luck.

I have seen similar posts, but none of them helped!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT1: added the output of journalctl $(type -p NetworkManager) for today when I tried to connect to university network. 
(Pardis Olum is the network which I am trying to connect to.)
My university is university of Tehran, and It doesn't require any kind of configuration before connecting.

```
Jul 22 10:18:14 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238494.8792] NetworkManager (version 1.10.6) is starting... (for the first time)
Jul 22 10:18:14 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238494.8792] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-chang
Jul 22 10:18:14 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238494.9132] manager[0x55a15b04b060]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Jul 22 10:18:14 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238494.9132] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Jul 22 10:18:14 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238494.9230] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Jul 22 10:18:14 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238494.9231] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "arian-Lenovo"
Jul 22 10:18:14 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238494.9234] dns-mgr[0x55a15b067140]: init: dns=systemd-resolved, rc-manager=symlink, plugin=systemd-resolved
Jul 22 10:18:14 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238494.9245] rfkill2: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:02:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill2) (driver rtl8
Jul 22 10:18:14 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238494.9247] rfkill0: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/rfkill/rfkill0) (platform d
Jul 22 10:18:14 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238494.9267] manager[0x55a15b04b060]: rfkill: WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Jul 22 10:18:14 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238494.9268] manager[0x55a15b04b060]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1054] init!
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1056]       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1056]       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1056] management mode: unmanaged
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1060] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0, iface: enp1s0)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1060] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0, iface: enp1s0): no ifupdown configuration fou
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1060] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0, iface: wlp2s0)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1060] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0, iface: wlp2s0): no ifupdown configuration fou
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1061] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1061] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1061] end _init.
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1061] settings: loaded plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list. (/usr/lib
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1061] settings: loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2016 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1061] (1527275712) ... get_connections.
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1061] (1527275712) ... get_connections (managed=false): return empty list.
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1178] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/arian (37a91a54-74b3-4e9b-a729-461ba0538fca,"arian")
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1276] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Library (abd4fff7-9dba-483c-bacc-364fecde524c,"Library")
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1427] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Etelsep (77fd0dcf-7cff-47be-b68e-0cfae2011ae1,"Etelsep")
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1520] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Pardise olum (19e734f6-05a4-4312-8a03-d0ad765edb8b,"Pardise olum
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1615] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AndroidAP (961e96e3-28b5-49f6-8786-7fc7a77e4f53,"AndroidAP")
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1708] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Arianhf (61623a21-1411-4e06-9544-3734bc3d2014,"Arianhf")
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1801] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Barbod (4d3f3f46-e3cb-4049-80f3-467540693e1a,"Barbod")
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1896] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/IBB (5c16f134-563a-4a60-a013-fa4323862551,"IBB")
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.1989] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MobinNet3869 (381b1ddf-c2c4-4f7c-8c07-1ab255f71abf,"MobinNet3869
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.2098] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MobinNet4305 (02c6b593-dd7f-4abd-bf2e-15c7d6b505df,"MobinNet4305
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.2198] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BgwW-YXJpYW4uaGVkYXlhdGlmYXI (908cb40e-9e5c-4cd7-b118-4d07ef4021
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.2295] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/mTnet (d76e9781-b0a4-462b-9ad6-562338cb1e90,"mTnet")
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.2392] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/lgk10 (f60cdae1-da52-4c01-a2d6-a160ade8146f,"lgk10")
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3558] get unmanaged devices count: 0
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3559] manager: rfkill: WiFi disabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3559] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3559] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3561] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'dhclient'
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3561] Loaded device plugin: NMBondDeviceFactory (internal)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3562] Loaded device plugin: NMBridgeDeviceFactory (internal)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3562] Loaded device plugin: NMDummyDeviceFactory (internal)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3562] Loaded device plugin: NMEthernetDeviceFactory (internal)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3562] Loaded device plugin: NMInfinibandDeviceFactory (internal)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3563] Loaded device plugin: NMIPTunnelDeviceFactory (internal)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3563] Loaded device plugin: NMMacsecDeviceFactory (internal)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3563] Loaded device plugin: NMMacvlanDeviceFactory (internal)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3563] Loaded device plugin: NMPppDeviceFactory (internal)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3563] Loaded device plugin: NMTunDeviceFactory (internal)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3563] Loaded device plugin: NMVethDeviceFactory (internal)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3564] Loaded device plugin: NMVlanDeviceFactory (internal)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3564] Loaded device plugin: NMVxlanDeviceFactory (internal)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.3572] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.5239] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.5868] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.5871] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.5874] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.5882] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.5888] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.5899] manager: (enp1s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.5910] keyfile: add connection in-memory (076c6cef-aa47-3aa3-9870-5f84ef151d50,"Wired connection 1")
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.5915] settings: (enp1s0): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.5925] device (enp1s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.5997] wifi-nl80211: (wlp2s0): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.6000] device (wlp2s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.6009] manager: (wlp2s0): new 802.11 WiFi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.6018] device (wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jul 22 10:18:15 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238495.6037] manager: rfkill: WiFi now enabled by radio killswitch
Jul 22 10:18:16 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238496.3745] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Jul 22 10:18:16 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238496.3752] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
Jul 22 10:18:16 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238496.3763] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Jul 22 10:18:16 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238496.3763] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
Jul 22 10:18:16 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238496.3784] bluez5: NAP: added interface 00:71:CC:7D:96:2A
Jul 22 10:18:16 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238496.4293] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Jul 22 10:18:16 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238496.4294] device (wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 22 10:18:21 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238501.5936] manager: startup complete
Jul 22 10:26:24 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238984.7004] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'Pardise olum' (19e734f6-05a4-4312-8a03-d0ad765edb8b)
Jul 22 10:26:24 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238984.7006] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="19e734f6-05a4-4312-8a03-d0ad765edb8b" name="Pardise olum" pid=2566 uid=1000 result="succe
Jul 22 10:26:24 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238984.7009] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 22 10:26:24 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238984.7011] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 22 10:26:24 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238984.7017] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 22 10:26:24 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238984.7020] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Pardise olum' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
Jul 22 10:26:24 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238984.7020] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Pardise olum'
Jul 22 10:26:24 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238984.7021] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul 22 10:26:24 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238984.7021] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Jul 22 10:26:24 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238984.7021] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
Jul 22 10:26:25 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238985.2251] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> authenticating
Jul 22 10:26:25 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238985.2313] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 22 10:26:25 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238985.2428] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Jul 22 10:26:25 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238985.2428] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'Pardise olum'.
Jul 22 10:26:25 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238985.2443] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 22 10:26:25 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238985.2520] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 22 10:26:25 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532238985.2535] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): dhclient started with pid 8116
Jul 22 10:27:11 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <warn>  [1532239031.0013] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): request timed out
Jul 22 10:27:11 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532239031.0013] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jul 22 10:27:11 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532239031.0176] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 8116
Jul 22 10:27:11 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532239031.0176] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed timeout -> done
Jul 22 10:27:11 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532239031.0179] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 22 10:27:11 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532239031.0181] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jul 22 10:27:11 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <warn>  [1532239031.0185] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Pardise olum'
Jul 22 10:27:11 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532239031.0194] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 22 10:27:11 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <warn>  [1532239031.0419] sup-iface[0x55a15b01fa40,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Jul 22 10:27:11 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532239031.0495] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul 22 10:27:12 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532239032.6283] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> disabled
Jul 22 10:27:13 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532239033.2465] supplicant: wpa_supplicant stopped
Jul 22 10:27:13 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532239033.2466] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disabled -> down
Jul 22 10:27:13 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532239033.2470] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'supplicant-failed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 22 10:27:23 arian-Lenovo NetworkManager[1229]: <info>  [1532239043.0048] supplicant: wpa_supplicant die count reset
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to have your network configured properly for the University.  But without knowing what University you're at or the network config they run, nobody can really provide you any assistance because we don't have enough information.  We need information such as what University you are at so we can try and chase down proper configuration instructions for you.

Comment: `journalctl $(type -p NetworkManager)` will give you some information